# No passwd entry for user

Tags: postgresql

Установил postgres на ubuntu.
Создаю пользователя `createuser --interactive`. Создаю бд `createdb db_name` Переключаюсь на созданного пользователя `sudo su - new_user` и выдает такое сообщение `No passwd entry for user new_user` Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Создать пользователя new_user не только в postgres, но и в системе. Ну или авторизоваться по паролю без всяких sudo su

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, проблема решилась. Пытаюсь подключиться уже через локальный dbeaver, но выдает ошибку.

Comment: разобрался. добавил удаленный доступ в конфиг.